# Get daily stock data from google or some other sites

Tags: web, finance, google-finance

Is there any sites to get the NASDAQ and NYSE stock price data by day?

I could find the historical prices by stock from google finance (csv)

```
https://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=NASDAQ:GOOG
```

However I want to get prices by day not by stock.

If I could get from google finance, it's great but I couldn't find.

Comment: Have you tried yahoo. Other alternative too in the answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040954/alternative-to-google-finance-api